# How can I instantiate OWIN IDataProtectionProvider in Azure Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, owin, azure-webjobs

I need an instance of `IDataProtectionProvider` to generate email confirmation tokens using the Identity Framework `UserManager` in an Azure Web Jobs worker:

```
var confirmToken = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

This crashes because a null `IUserTokenProvider<User, int>` was passed to the `UserManager<User, int>` upon constuction.

In the MVC application an instance is created like this:

```
public class OWINStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var dataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
```

But of course, Azure Web Jobs doesn't have an `OWINStartup` hook. Any advice?

Comment: You can send the information needed to generate the token in a queue message. And use that message in your WebJob to do what's needed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've settled for in the meantime. I just send the token along. But preferably, I would like to be able to generate it in the webjob. I am generating the token and sending the email in response to an event, after all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) source code for the [OWIN startup context](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/OwinAppContext.cs) you can see the default implementation of the `DataProtectionProvider` is a `MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider`.  Unfortunately this class is not exposed to us, only the [`DpapiDataProtectionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.dataprotection.dpapidataprotectionprovider(v=vs.113).aspx) which will not work when [hosted in azure](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2439).

You can find the implementation of the `MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider` [here](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/DataProtection/MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider.cs).  You will need to also implement your own `MachineKeyDataProtector` as seen [here](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/DataProtection/MachineKeyDataProtector.cs).  These are not difficult implmentations and are essentially wrappers around [`MachineKey.Protect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`MachineKey.Unprotect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.unprotect(v=vs.110).aspx).

The implementation for `MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider` and `MachineKeyDataProtector` from the [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) project source ([apache 2.0 license](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#LICENSE.txt)):

```
internal class MachineKeyProtectionProvider : IDataProtectionProvider
{
    public IDataProtector Create(params string[] purposes)
    {
        return new MachineKeyDataProtector(purposes);
    }
}

internal class MachineKeyDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purposes;

    public MachineKeyDataProtector(string[] purposes)
    {
        _purposes = purposes;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Protect(userData, _purposes);
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purposes);
    }
}
```

Once you have that implemented it is easy to plug into the `UserManager`:

```
var usermanager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
var machineKeyProtectionProvider = new MachineKeyProtectionProvider();
usermanager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(machineKeyProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

Hope that helps get you in the right direction.

Comment: This does work.. kind of. But, since the `MachineKeyDataProtector ` is being used outside of the web app (in the web job), it uses it's own keys (not any that you might speficy in the web.config of the web app). So any token you generate here won't then be accepted as valid by the web app :( Not sure of a solution to this apart from rolling a different IDataProtector....

Comment: @MattRoberts Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Links for [MachineKeyDataProtector](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/DataProtection/MachineKeyDataProtector.cs) and [MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/DataProtection/MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider.cs) have changed. They moved to github. (well, all links have changed, but those are the two i just needed ;) )

Comment: @Høgsdal did either of you find a solution? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @GregVeres This is a long time ago so I can't exactly remember what I did. But I have upvoted jsturtevant and Matt Roberts posts so those would have let me to a solution. Hope this helps.